# Execute a store procedure with parameters on MySQL with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm working with VS 2010 Net Framework 3.5 and MySQL 5.1, with C#

Basically I have some parameters with different types (int, string, boolean, etc) and I need to send them to a MySQL parameter as input vars.

The last layer of my app is doing this:

```
            public Boolean ExecuteProcedure(string ProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> ParameterCollection) {

                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
                Command.Parameters.AddRange(ParameterCollection.ToArray<SqlParameter>());
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
(... etc etc)
```

So basically I need to convert on previous layers all my data into a List of SQL Parameters.

My questions are:

- This is a good idea? Maybe I sent another kind of object to the
  ExecuteProcedure function?
- Which is the better way to convert my vars of different kind into SQLParameter?
- Which limitations of use this kind of programming could be?

**UPDATE:**

My question is related to the communication between the layers. For example, the previous layer can be...

```
                List<SqlParameter> INParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            INParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("error_code",error_code));
            INParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("error_description",error_description));
            SysDB.ExecuteProcedure("sys_log_insert_error", INParameters);
```

Is this a good way to do this?

Thanks and kind regards,

Comment: `SqlParameter` works with MySql?  I thought that was only for SQL Server.

Comment: well, its working fine for me, the connector has the MySQLParameter but it really doesnt care, i dont know why.

Comment: i think the key is on the commander

Comment: Your update code looks fine to me. If you don't want the top layer to know anything about SQL or SQLParameters then you can pass something more generic like a KeyValuePairs..

Comment: @banging that's the main idea about my question, can you answer (pseudo code, doesnt care) with that idea of keyvaluepairs or something like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the top layer to know anything about SQL or SQLParameters, you can pass something more generic like `KeyValuePair` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

I would change `ExecuteProcedure` to something like this >>

`public Boolean ExecuteProcedure(string ProcedureName, params KeyValuePair<String, Object>[] ParameterCollection) { ... }`

You may also have some helper method that takes in the `KeyValuePair`s which you call in `ExecuteProcedure` to transform them into `SQLParameter` objects that you can then use in your query..

I think you get the point..

Answer (score 1):

see this article you can only specify in and out but not type 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36484/Working-C-code-for-MySql-Stored-Procedures-IN-OUT

Comment: yeah i know, is not my problem the connection to the database, the problem or my question is about the communication between the layers. One layer with the function get a list of sqlparameters and the another one has a lot of different types of vars that i need to transform in order to create a sqlparameter list. Please review my questions with bullets

Comment: because you want only a technical translation of type var to sql parameter a helper will be the best or a DTO .

Comment: thank you leandro I see that you are interesting about conception, so i will give you a good link talking about DDD architecture used by best developpers you will learn best practices about layers http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/     enjoy